# how to count words in a string omitting spaces ' '

Tags: java, string, text

Write a method called wordCount that accepts a String as its parameter and returns the number of words in the String. A word is a sequence of one or more nonspace characters (any character other than ' '). For example, the call wordCount("hello") should return 1, the call wordCount("how are you?") should return 3, the call wordCount(" this string has wide spaces ") should return 5, and the call wordCount(" ") should return 0

Comment: Copy-pasted homework question, yaaay!

Comment: I think it's interesting how you *genuinely* believe that people will actually feel obligated to answer this question. If you don't plan on putting in **ANY** effort, why even bother to take a programming course?

Answer (score 0):

```
String trimmedInput = input.trim();
int wordsInSentence = trimmedInput .isEmpty() ? 0 : trimmedInput.split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect; it will return 6 for " this string has wide spaces "

Answer (score 0):

```
input =  input.trim()
return input.empty()?0:input.split("\\s+").length
```